# How to run multiple choices from a parameter at once?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a pipeline with multiple choice parameters. For one of the choice parameters (e.g. Param A), it contains multiple choices (e.g. {A, B, C, D, E, F}). How can I build my pipeline with all of the choices from Param A at once. My current implementation makes me select a choice from a dropdown list on each build. This forces me to have to build one by one with each selected choice. Instead, I want to be able to build just a single time for all of the choices for Param A (e.g. I run my build and a build is run for choice A, then right after a build is run for choice B, then C, and so on allowing me to not have to run the build one by one for each choice).

I have scoured stack overflow and google for answers but I have yet to come up with any clear answer.

Comment: How you are showing them? What's the problem to show them all at once?

Comment: I need them to build all at once in a single build.